# Exit command without waiting to finish

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, spark-ar-studio

I am trying to export SparkAR files using SparkAR CLI however after script successfully export files it does not exit the process for example:

```
sparkTerminalBinaryWindows.exe export .\Project.arproj -d .\exportDestination
```

When I run this command it outputs:

```
Starting to export project file at path: ".\Project.arproj"...
Successfully exported project file at path ".\Project.arproj" to path ".\exportDestination\Project.arexport".
```

However after this output process not exits so if I run something like this

```
sparkTerminalBinaryWindows.exe export .\Project.arproj -d .\exportDestination && echo "Second command"
```

second command `echo "Second command"` never runs

What can be done is

1. Listen the output of the first command and when i see keyword "Successfully" exit the command
2. Process takes maximum 10 seconds to finish so maybe i can give a timeout to first command and eventually it will exit with timeout after 10 seconds

However I have no experience on Windows terminal or PowerShell. I tried to search for a solutions but I couldn't find anything.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: So what are you running this in? PowerShell or cmd? If the process never ends it's not wonder you never see the output of the following command.

Comment: It's possible the command is poorly written and detaches the console or keeps waiting for input or suchlike. See what happens if you run it using `Start-Job` instead (`Start-Job { ... } | Wait-Job | Receive-Job`). If it genuinely never finishes you'd need to kill it, but that's not usually what you want to do.

Comment: I tried it both in powershell and cmd . The thing is , cli is written by facebook sparkar team and reporting a bug to them takes 30+ days to patch it so i am trying to solve it on my own to automate my process. I am trying to find a solution to kill the process after 10 seconds or after i see an output with keyword "Successfully"

Comment: I've tried same thing on a mac, it works but after successfully exporting I get : Segmentation fault: 11. 
I use this command : 
sparkTerminalAppleMac export projName.arproj -d $(pwd)

Answer (score 0):

Pipe it to where-object and then select-object -first.  The select will kill the pipe.

```
& { while (1) { sleep 5; 'successfully' } } | 
  where { $_ -match 'successfully' } | select -first 1

successfully
```